# DevTool, unable to hide columns in the network tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have too many column in the network tab, I cannot hide them. As you can see in the image below columns are deselected. It's not very readable.
I already tried reinstall Chrome and purge all Chrome data.
What else can I try?

[image: devtool]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has already been tracked on the Chromium bug tracker (Issue ID 1145150) and is marked as resolved.
I therefore assume this fix will be included in an upcoming Chrome release.

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless

Comment: @AmirhosseinYari I've edited my comment, is that better?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Google Chrome Canary.  For me, the problem went away when I updated.  I'm now on version Version 88.0.4320.0.  My network tab went back to these columns:

[image]