# Cant hide columns in chrome dev tools network tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

After a recent update to Chrome dev (88.0.4315.5), all the possible columns in the network tab are shown and i cant hide any of them. I've tried right clicking the header and unchecking but nothing changes.
[here's a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KI77.png)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749597/devtool-unable-to-hide-columns-in-the-network-tab/64766095#64766095. I've answered over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also encountered this problem today, I'm using Chromium Nightly build.
Downgraded to stable, and everything fixed